# Azure Logic App gets csv file from SFTP Server and inserts into Mysql in app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Can someone please recommend the best way of doing this using Azure Logic App:

That what i do:

1. Connect to SFTP Server
   2)Get file content
   3)insert row

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In logic App you can directly add the connectors that you wanted. Based on your requirement you can add Get file content action from SFTP connector and Insert Row action from SQL server connection. The data that you are receiving from SFTP connection will be passed to your SQL Table as per your requirement using `Insert row` action of SQL Server.

After Adding the Insert row action you need to specify the table to which you are storing the data which intern's generates columns for the table.

Here is the screenshot of the Logic App for your reference

[image]

**REFERENCES:**
[Connecting to SFTP server using azure logic apps | Coding Canvas](https://codingcanvas.com/connecting-to-sftp-server-using-azure-logic-apps/)

Comment: I used the same thing but when i try to fill parameter to insert row i can't get the values, i added the image in my post

Comment: Are you mean to say that the values are not reflected in the database after insertion?

Comment: i mean i can't match the value in csv  to items in database,for example id in cs file to id in database,name to name etc

Comment: I can't insert row in sql server without change the format of csv how can i match the conntent of my csv file to items in database?